# What are the best Practices in designing a Landing Page Mobile UI with a group of different buttons with different functionalities

Tags: interface-design, design-principles, mobile, google-material-design, user-experience

For a Application I am working on, There are 5-6 differenr services which will be available to user as soon as they login.
These services will be present as a seperate button , so that user just click or "say" and enter that service menu.

What are some good design practices I should undertake so as to use available screen space and make a decent grid-style Button menu.

[image: Sample Image and services]

The image I'm attaching is the mockup of the available services.

What should be the style of this menu?
Please share any references or designs.!

Comment: The possibilities of a design for a 6-button screen are practically infinite. This question is too broad in my opinion.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to narrow it down? Only thing I want to know is how to place 6 buttons on a mobile screen without making screen too empty!

Comment: Add some design, to taste. You have the ingredients, you know what to cook, and have the recipe. All you need do is add your particular favourite flavours. "best practices" is a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a grid of 2*3 that spans across all the screen. Each grid cell will be approx. a rectangle. Add an icon to each one, maybe a color if it's in your design system.
It's very responsive and a known pattern so the user is familiar with it.

Something like this:

[image: example of grid]

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, i guess, I have to experiment with these rectangular button to make it fill the screen